# Trying to make letters draggable to make a word

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to make letters be draggable to make a word. But for some reason it will just not work.

My HTML:

```
    <html>
  <head>
    <title>Word Maker</title>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='script.js'></script>
     <script src="js/jquery-1.6.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js" type="type/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/ui/jquery.ui.draggable.js" type="type/javascript"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="letters" class="makeDraggable">
        <div id="letter1" class="makeDraggable">
          <p>w</p>
        </div>
    <div id="letter2" class="makeDraggable">
      <p>p</p>
      </div>
    <div id="letter3" class="makeDraggable">
      <p>i</p>
    </div>
    <div id="letter4" class="makeDraggable">
      <p>r</p>
    </div>
    <div id="letter5" class="makeDraggable">
      <p>o</p>
    </div>
    <div id="letter6" class="makeDraggable">
      <p>m</p>
    </div>
    <div id="letter7" class="makeDraggable">
      <p>l</p>
    </div>
    <div id="letter8" class="makeDraggable">
      <p>l</p>
    </div>
    <div id="letter9" class="makeDraggable">
      <p>w</p>
    </div>
    <div id="letter10" class="makeDraggable">
      <p>y</p>
    </div>
    <div id="letter11" class="makeDraggable">
      <p>u</p>
    </div>
    <div id="letter12" class="makeDraggable">
      <p>o</p>
    </div>
    <div id="letter13" class="makeDraggable">
      <p>g</p>
    </div>
    <div id="letter14" class="makeDraggable">
      <p>t</p>
    </div>
    <div id="letter15" class="makeDraggable">
      <p>o</p>
    </div>
    <div id="letter16" class="makeDraggable">
      <p>o</p>
    </div>
  <div id="letter17" class="makeDraggable">
    <p>i</p>
    </div>
    <div id="letter18" class="makeDraggable">
      <p>t</p>
    </div>
    <div id="letter19" class="makeDraggable">
      <p>h</p>
    </div>
    <div id="letter20" class="makeDraggable">
      <p>e</p>
    </div>
    <div id="letter21" class="makeDraggable">
      <p>m</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

JS code:

```
$(function() {
    $("letters").draggable();
});
```

Comment: `It doesn't work` Well, what does it do?

Comment: just a second...jquery is busy washing your dishes

Comment: @Ark Uhh, what? I assume that's supposed to be a joke but it makes absolutely no sense.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist tip: he was not using jquery tag :)

Comment: @Ark Oh, ok. Well, you managed to get *one* of the words necessary to communicate that sentiment in your original comment, so I guess we'll consider that a success.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist actually i edited to show jquery tag, im waitting aproval...

Comment: Just change `$("letters").draggable();` to `$(".makeDraggable").draggable();`. No dad is needed.

Comment: @Ark while adding a tag is valid edit, please try to fix some more things in the post when editing. (Your suggestion was almost rejected as too minor because of that)

Answer (score 1):

You should try applying `.draggable()` to all your elements with class `makeDraggable`.
Take a look at [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/VwT2U/). Simply changing your jquery selector will allow you to make the single letters draggable.

Comment: I just copied what you had in there and it doesnt work. but it worked on that site you had it on.

Comment: +1, but OP here need [a silver spoon](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14626849/trying-to-make-letters-draggable-to-make-a-word#comment20429416_14626849) :)

Answer (score 0):

The first problem you have is `$('letters')`. That selector is telling jQuery to find all elements that were created by a `<letter>` tag, which is none.

You may have meant `$('#letters')` instead, which would select one element, the `<div>` with an `id` of `letters`.

You may benefit from some additional reading about [jQuery selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).

Answer (score 0):

Probably what you want to use is .sortable(), it's better to create words, take a look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/CqqxE/

All you have to do in you js is:

```
$(function () {
    $("#letters").sortable();
});
```

Then you can add some fancy css to turn things cooler

```
.makeDraggable {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: #CDE;
    float: left; /* Important to align letters */
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.makeDraggable:active {
    background-color: #DCC;
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
}
```

---

### **EDIT #1:**

Of course, now you don't need all those classes...
http://jsfiddle.net/promatik/CqqxE/1/

Creating words:

```
<div class="word">
    <div>w</div>
    <div>o</div>
    <div>r</div>
    <div>d</div>
</div>
<div class="word">
    <div>a</div>
    <div>n</div>
    <div>o</div>
    <div>t</div>
    <div>h</div>
    <div>e</div>
    <div>r</div>
</div>
```

And JS:

```
$(function () {
    $(".word").sortable();
});
```